# OK to copy a CRITICAL_SECTION?

Tags: c, winapi, synchronization

One can use a CRITICAL_SECTION variable to get mutual exclusion.

My question is: does CRITICAL_SECTION support copying? If I pass one by value to another thread, can I know for sure that mutual exclusion will work?

I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is "you cannot do that", but it'd be nice to have some sort of official confirmation. I wasn't able to find a statement either way in the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  A `CRITICAL_SECTION` cannot be copied.  [MSDN states this explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472(v=VS.85).aspx):

> A critical section object cannot be moved or copied.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search through the headers reveals that the structure is defined in `winnt.h`, and this definition clearly seems to indicate that copying the structure wouldn't work.

```
typedef struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION {
    PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG DebugInfo;

    //
    //  The following three fields control entering and exiting the critical
    //  section for the resource
    //

    LONG LockCount;
    LONG RecursionCount;
    HANDLE OwningThread;        // from the thread's ClientId->UniqueThread
    HANDLE LockSemaphore;
    ULONG_PTR SpinCount;        // force size on 64-bit systems when packed
} RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION, *PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION;
```

That said, I have no idea why these internal counters are stored in a user-space structure, i.e. what will happen if a program modifies these?

Comment: The documentation clearly states that you cannot modify the contents of a `CRITICAL_SECTION`:  "The process must also not modify the object, but must treat it as logically opaque."

Comment: Which is why I raised this question. What does "cannot" mean? It's uncommon for anything beyond a handle to be manipulable by user programs.

Comment: If an API says that a consumer of the API _must_ not do something, that means "if you do this, all bets are off."

Comment: And a critical section is intended to be *FAST*.  That means that it can't spend the time entering the kernel and leaving to enter.  If you want a synchronization object that provides similar semantics to a critical section, use a mutex object.  Then you don't have to worry about all those internal details being exposed ot the application.  Of course your application will be a lot slower than the critical section but that's the price you pay for architectural purity.