# Cross-Platform Condition Variable troubles

Tags: c++, multithreading, cross-platform, deadlock

In our project, we need to implement os *dependent* abstractions (like file, socket, thread...) for each os (linux, android, osx and win). 
The general iter for implementing os abstraction is:

1. Write an os *independent* class header which defines methods that are common for each os (Cond).
2. Write an os *depentent* implementation using os function (e.g. pthread_cond, win32 ConditionVariable).
3. link and build through cmake.

I have encountered problems implementing Condition Variable in Windows.
I need to wrap CriticalSection function in my Mutex class because ConditionVariable in windows works with critical sections. Of course, i use standard posix solution on posix systems.

here's the code:

1.a) Header (linux) - **Cond.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <pthread.h>
#include "Types.h"
#include "Mutex.h"
#include "OS.h"

Class Cond
{
public:

                Cond();
                ~Cond();

    void        signal();
    void        wait(Mutex& mutex);

private:

    pthread_cond_t  m_cond;
};
```

1.b) Header (win) - **Cond.h**

```
#pragam once

#include <windows.h>
#include "Types.h"
#include "Mutex.h"
#include "OS.h"

class Cond
{
public:
                    Cond();
                    ~Cond();

    void            signal();
    void            wait(Mutex& mutex);

private:

    CONDITION_VARIABLE      m_cond;
};
```

as you can see, the interface is common, but types differs.

2.a) Implementation (linux) - **Cond.cpp**

```
#include "Cond.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cond::Cond()
{
    memset(&m_cond, 0, sizeof(pthread_cond_t));

    pthread_cond_init(&m_cond, NULL);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cond::~Cond()
{
    pthread_cond_destroy(&m_cond);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Cond::signal()
{
    pthread_cond_signal(&m_cond);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Cond::wait(Mutex& mutex)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&m_cond, &(mutex.m_mutex));
}
```

linux implementation of condition variable works well!

2.b) Implementation (win) - **Cond.cpp**

```
#include "Cond.h"

Cond::Cond()
{
    InitializeConditionVariable(&m_cond);
}

Cond::~Cond()
{

}

void Cond::signal()
{
    WakeConditionVariable(&m_cond);
}

void Cond::wait(Mutex& mutex)
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs = mutex.handle(); // returns CRITICAL_SECTION

    SleepConditionVariableCS(&m_cond, &cs, INFINITE);
}
```

**This implementation compiles but does not works (deadlock).**

Here's an example which works on linux and doesn't works on Win:

```
void ResourceManager::flush()
{
    check_load_queue();

    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for all the resources to be loaded
        // by the background thread
        m_loading_mutex.lock(); 
        while (m_loading_queue.size() > 0)
        {
            m_all_loaded.wait(m_loading_mutex);  //Cond
        }
        m_loading_mutex.unlock();

        // When all loaded, bring them online
        bring_loaded_online();

        return;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Windows Critical Section Wrapper - Mutex.h & Mutex.cpp

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include "Types.h"
#include "OS.h"


class Mutex
{
public:

                        Mutex();
                        ~Mutex();

    void                lock();
    void                unlock();

    CRITICAL_SECTION    handle();

private:

    CRITICAL_SECTION    m_cs;

    friend class        Cond;
};
```

---

```
#include "Mutex.h"

namespace crown
{
namespace os
{

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mutex::Mutex()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mutex::~Mutex()
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Mutex::lock()
{
    TryEnterCriticalSection(&m_cs); 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Mutex::unlock()
{
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRITICAL_SECTION Mutex::handle()
{
    return m_cs;
}
```

Could you explaine me why? Solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: added win Mutex which is a critical section wrapper

Comment: Quoting MSDN: "A critical section object cannot be moved or copied."

Comment: @nos making Cond friend of Mutex i can do (in Cond::wait): SleepConditionVariableCS(&m_cond, &mutex.m_cs, 5000); It's legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly wrong:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION Mutex::handle()
{
    return m_cs;
}
```

You're returning a copy of a CRITICAL_SECTION, which you [cannot do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269266/ok-to-copy-a-critical-section). Return a reference or pointer instead.

As mentioned in comments, you should also implement private copy constructor and assignment operators in your Mutex and Cond class, as the platform dependent mutex (such as pthread_mutex_t) and condition variables cannot be copied - doing so results in undefined behavior when using these objects

Comment: making Cond friend of Mutex i can do (in Cond::wait): SleepConditionVariableCS(&m_cond, &mutex.m_cs, 5000); It's legal?

Answer (score 2):

Why? No idea. Solution: use portable and freely available libraries that wrap the platform dependencies.

- `std::thread` for multithreading: `#include <thread>`
- [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) for networking: `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`
- [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for file systems: `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`

The Boost libraries are often a pre-cursor to the Standard Library. Almost all the threading features were available in [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread.html) several years before the latest C++11 Standard. It's expected that Boost.Asio and Boost.Filesystem will be building blocks for standardization as well.

To get it working in CMake, [install Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html) and use something like

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread asio filesystem REQUIRED)
```

Comment: +1 for the _don't reinvent the wheel_ solution. Personally I use http://pocoproject.org/ in my project (because of it has a VxWorks version). It is an interesting library.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget I have no experience with Poco but it sounds interesting as well. Facebook Folly is another source of interesting libraries.

Comment: std::thread is not so portable right now (otherwise i have used it). Moreover we don't want add more dependencies to our project

Comment: @mikymod you will add less rather than more dependencies because you can eliminate `phtread` and `win32thread`, and similarly for the platofrm-specific networking and filesystem. And all the Boost sublibraries are packaged, so there is really only 1 dependency. That's the whole point of using the Standard Library and its Boost cousin. It's a long run investment that will pay huge dividends.

Comment: @mikymod And you can always cheat by using the `bcp` tool in Boost to extract all the required headers and integrate these directly into your project :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex i don't want use 3rd party lib because: 1) i don't use malloc/dealloc/realloc but a custom allocator (previous function are forbidden); 2) try/catch blocks are also forbidden; BTW, when std::thread becomes more supported, then i will use it