# How to make a dictionary of synchronization objects?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

What I need is something like `std::map<std::string, CCriticalSection>` but CCriticalSection is non-copyable. Instead of `CCriticalSection` I thought I could use `CRICITAL_SECTION` but it's also [not possible to copy or move objects of this type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269274/237483). Because it's a very old project, I'm restricted to use MFC and VC6. I would like to access the synchronization objects in following manner (the following code does not work and is just an idea how I would like to use the dicionary):

```
// global variable
std::map<std::string, CCriticalSection> csec;

unsigned int somefunc(std::string ip)
{
    CSingleLock lock(&csec[ip], TRUE);
    // do something
}
```

So my question is, how to make a dictionary of synchronization objects using MFC and VC6?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a map of pointers to critical sections:

```
std::map<std::string, CCriticalSection *> csec;

// add
csec["key1"] = new CCriticalSection();

// access
CSingleLock lock(csec[ip], TRUE);

// don't forget to delete after use
for (std::map<std::string, CCriticalSection *>::iterator i = csec.begin();
     i != csec.end(); ++i)
    delete i->second;
```