# Access Violation Exception EnterCriticalSection WinAPI C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I don't understand what is causing this error

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void EnterCriticalSection(ref IntPtr lpCriticalSection);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void LeaveCriticalSection(ref IntPtr lpCriticalSection);

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unsafe
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr criticalSection = new IntPtr();
            EnterCriticalSection(ref criticalSection);
            LeaveCriticalSection(ref criticalSection);
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried in Visual Studio to change the build type from Any CPU to x86, but it didn't bring results.

Comment: Firstly, you must remove the `ref`s. Secondly, you cannot enter a critical section that hasn't been [initialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection). Thirdly, you don't need to use critical sections in C#.

Comment: Do you really need a low-level critical section? C# has built-in synchronization features such as `lock`.

Comment: read the manual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-entercriticalsection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`EnterCriticalSection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-entercriticalsection) expects to be given a pointer to a `CRITICAL_SECTION` struct that has been initialized with either [`InitializeCriticalSection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection) or [`InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionandspincount).

But instead, you are giving it a reference to an uninitialized `IntPtr` that doesn't point anywhere meaningful. Hence the crash when `EnterCriticalSection()` tries to access a struct that doesn't exist.

The correct code should look more like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CRITICAL_SECTION
{
    public IntPtr DebugInfo;
    public int LockCount;
    public int RecursionCount;
    public IntPtr OwningThread;
    public IntPtr LockSemaphore;
    public UIntPtr SpinCount;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void InitializeCriticalSection(ref CRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void DeleteCriticalSection(ref CRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void EnterCriticalSection(ref CRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void LeaveCriticalSection(ref CRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection);

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unsafe
    {
        try
        {
            CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection = new CRITICAL_SECTION();
            InitializeCriticalSection(ref criticalSection);
            EnterCriticalSection(ref criticalSection);
            LeaveCriticalSection(ref criticalSection);
            DeleteCriticalSection(ref criticalSection);
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

However, you really don't need to use `CRITICAL_SECTION` in C#, use the [`lock` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) instead, or a [synchronization primitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) like [`System.Threading.Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor).

Comment: Would this work at all if GC decides to move the struct between the invocations? I.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269274/11683.

Comment: A `struct` is a value type, it can't be moved, only copied (but the `CRITICAL_SECTION` docs say it can't be copied or moved). `CRITICAL_SECTION` contains only other value types as its members. So, it is not subject to garbage collection, unless it is contained as a member of an object type, then the containing object is garbage-collected.